# Does Google AdSense show the revenue by day or by week?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, revenue

In my site, Google Analytics (under `Behavior` > `Overview`) shows a revenue of **$0.58**. However, it is not clear if this is for the day or for the entire week.

The timeline shows **May 5** to **May 11**, so I am thinking this revenue is for the week, but as can be seen in the screenshot below, **Day** is also chosen, so I am confused which of the two the revenue of `$0.58` refers to.

[image: Google Analytics screenshot of revenue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *day* icon refers to the interval of the graph along the horizontal axis.

In your case, the period of interest is the week of May 5th - May 11th broken down by days.  If you choose *hour* you will see a more detailed graph of the same period, but the same revenue.  However if you change the breadth of dates e.g. last month, you will see a completely different set of results and likely a different amount of revenue.

The graph shows that you had a slight increase in page views over the week being examined and the table shows you earned 58c over that period.

Comment: $0.58 for the entire week.. Would you consider this a fine start? The site is about 2 and a half months old.

Comment: Sure it is a start...but it has taken me quite a while to get to $100 a week.